# How to redirect a function call to a user-defined one of the same name?

Tags: c, linker

Environment:

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- Compiler: GCC 5.4.0

I have two dependent libraries (either static or shared, not sure whether this affects), `libA` and `libB`. A function `foo()` is defined in `libA`, and is called in `libB`. Now I have my application code `app.c` directly call functions from `libB` which will eventually call `foo()`. A simple workflow is `app.c -> libB.a -> libA.a -> foo()`.

However, I want to change how `foo()` is implemented for some particular purpose. I hope `app.c` can have a magic function, if called, redirecting the call to `foo()` to the one provided by `app.c`. So the workflow, if could be achieved, should be

```
app.c -> libB.a -(other than foo())-> libA.a
 |      /
 |  (to call foo())
 v   /
foo()
```

The embarrassment is that I have fully control on `app.c` but minimal or even no access to those libraries. So is it possible to achieve such idea and how?

**Update**

As mentioned in comments, well missing this can lead to a totally different way of solution, the redirection is better configurable and happens at runtime. This is for test purpose so that normally the workflow should be what it is while only changes itself when testing is performed.

Comment: Just define a function named `foo` in `app.c`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I actually know this method. But then I have to conditional compile using macro directive. The redirection is not permanent and I hope this can be configurable via a condition variable, like `testrun = true / false`.

Comment: If you need to select which one you call at run time with e.g. a command line parameter, then this is rather more involved. You should have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: Your description is unclear, but you seem to be describing interposition or something similar. Search for “interposition”, “interpose”, or “interposing” for information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully clearer statement of the problem: `app.c` calls `bar()`, which is defined in `libB.a`. `bar()` calls `foo()`, which is defined in `libA.a`.

Desired outcome: *at runtime*, *optionally* redirect the call to `foo()` to an alternate implementation `foo_other()` depending on command line argument or environment variable.

---

Solution (assuming the signature of `foo` is `int foo(void)`):

1. Add this code to `app.c`:

```
int foo_other()
{
  printf("%s in %s:%d\n", __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__);
  return 42;
}

int __real_foo();
int __wrap_foo()
{
  printf("%s in %s:%d\n", __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__);
  if (getenv("TTT") != NULL) return foo_other();
  return __real_foo();
}
```

2. Link your application as follows:

```
gcc app.c  libB.a libA.a -Wl,--wrap,foo
```

Result:

```
$ ./a.out
bar in bar.c:6
__wrap_foo in main.c:19
foo in foo.c:4

$ TTT=1 ./a.out
bar in bar.c:6
__wrap_foo in main.c:19
foo_other in main.c:13
```

Obviously you can remove the debug `printf` calls and change the mechanism used to switch between real `foo()` and `foo_other()` as you need.

P.S. For documentation for the linker `--wrap` flag, see `man ld`.

[Example](https://drewdevault.com/2016/07/19/Using-Wl-wrap-for-mocking-in-C.html) of using `--wrap` for mocking.

When using shared libraries, this approach will not work. But a different equivalent [approach](https://hackerboss.com/overriding-system-functions-for-fun-and-profit/) is available via function interpositioning.